# Use of unresolved identifier 'function' when accessing Rust code using the Swift C Bridge

Tags: c, swift, rust, ffi, bridge

I'm trying to add a C bridge from a Swift macOS app to a Rust program via `cargo lipo`. I can get a simple function that takes no input and prints "Hello", but my Rust program's input is a struct of strings and arrays of strings. I followed fluffyemily's [Mozilla post](https://mozilla.github.io/firefox-browser-architecture/experiments/2017-09-06-rust-on-ios.html) on setting up `cargo lipo` in a Swift macOS app and hoped I could simply pass in a struct similar to what we see here [in @Shepmaster's helpful article on Rust FFI or Rust bridges to other languages](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/tuples/)

I can't get past this error when I build the XCode Swift app:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'init_loop_volumes'
```

Here's what I'm working with:

**rust_bindings.h**

```
// #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
// #include <inttypes.h>

//const char* init_loop_volumes(const char* to);
void simple();
void init_loop_volumes(const struct args);
```

**rust_bindings_header.h**

```
#ifndef rust_bindings_header_h
#define rust_bindings_header_h

#import "rust_bindings.h"

#endif /* rust_bindings_header_h */
```

**lib.rs**

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn init_loop_volumes(args: fv_structopt::VacuumMac) {
    let check_process_struct = init(args);
    loop_volumes(check_process_struct.c, false);
    println!("test")
}
```

**structs.rs**

```rust
#[repr(C)]
pub struct VacuumMac {
    pub deposit_path: std::path::PathBuf,
    pub exclude_paths: Vec<std::path::PathBuf>,
    pub volumes_path: std::path::PathBuf,
    pub log_path: std::path::PathBuf,
    pub file_types: Vec<String>,
    pub options: Vec<String>,
}
```

**Operation.swift**

```swift
  override func main() {
    init_loop_volumes(self.vacuumCli)
    // simple() <- this works
  }
```

**Structs.swift**

```swift
public struct VacuumCli {
  var deposit_path = String();
  var exclude_paths = [String]();
  var volume_path = String();
  var log_path = String();
  var file_types = [String]();
  var options = [String]();
}
```

This is a little tricky to debug as `cargo lipo` doesn't give a report of what it produced into the `lib.a` achieve file. Sometimes I'll turn `init_loop_volumes` into a function that just prints "Hello" and I still get that error even after cleaning the build in XCode, which makes me think XCode is caching my `rust_bindings.h` somewhere other that what it shows in the file-tree/editor.

Since I'm working with C bridge strings, do I have to do the `CStr` conversions?

Comment: I don't think that `PathBuf` and `Vec` are valid to be used in a FFI context like that.

Comment: *fluffyemily's Mozilla post* — link?

Comment: You probably want to follow http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/objects/ instead.

Comment: @Shepmaster, Mozilla link added. I also made this simple working example of a Swift-Rust C bridge with references to the Mozilla article and your Rust FFI page here: https://github.com/mikeumus/Sandboxed-Rust-C-Bridge